# Fill a column of a numpy array with another array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have:

```
x = np.zeros((96,11,11,2,10),dtype=np.float64)
y = np.array([0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100],dtype=np.float64)
x[:,:,:,0,0] = y
print x[0,:,:,0,0]
```

i get:

```
[[   0.   10.   20.   30.   40.   50.   60.   70.   80.   90.  100.]
 [   0.   10.   20.   30.   40.   50.   60.   70.   80.   90.  100.]
 [   0.   10.   20.   30.   40.   50.   60.   70.   80.   90.  100.]
 [   0.   10.   20.   30.   40.   50.   60.   70.   80.   90.  100.]
 [   0.   10.   20.   30.   40.   50.   60.   70.   80.   90.  100.]
 [   0.   10.   20.   30.   40.   50.   60.   70.   80.   90.  100.]
 [   0.   10.   20.   30.   40.   50.   60.   70.   80.   90.  100.]
 [   0.   10.   20.   30.   40.   50.   60.   70.   80.   90.  100.]
 [   0.   10.   20.   30.   40.   50.   60.   70.   80.   90.  100.]
 [   0.   10.   20.   30.   40.   50.   60.   70.   80.   90.  100.]
 [   0.   10.   20.   30.   40.   50.   60.   70.   80.   90.  100.]]
```

but I want the output (for any i in first dimension) to be the transpose of this. ie fill columns instead of rows

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is this your actual example? Because I don't see how you can assign a 1D array to a 3D slice, and when I try it, as expected, `x[:,:,:,0,0] = y` raises `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (20,11,11) (10)`.

Comment: no, its not. I'll edit it now

Comment: now its the real example

Comment: I asked the question again in a better way here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18763717/assigning-to-multi-dimensional-array

Comment: @Sammy It is recommend that you edit your question then to ask a new one *if* the question is, in effect, the same.

Answer (score 3):

You need to change `y` from 1D to 2D (with one column):

```
x[:,:,:,0,0] = y[:, np.newaxis]
```

or,

```
x[:,:,:,0,0] = y.reshape(11,1)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want the output to be the transpose, just do:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.zeros((96,11,11,2,10),dtype=np.float64)
>>> y = np.array([0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100],dtype=np.float64)
>>> for i in range(x.shape[0]):
>>>    x[i,:,:,0,0] = x[i,:,:,0,0].T
>>> print x[0,:,:,0,0]
 [[   0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.]
  [  10.   10.   10.   10.   10.   10.   10.   10.   10.   10.   10.]
  [  20.   20.   20.   20.   20.   20.   20.   20.   20.   20.   20.]
  [  30.   30.   30.   30.   30.   30.   30.   30.   30.   30.   30.]
  [  40.   40.   40.   40.   40.   40.   40.   40.   40.   40.   40.]
  [  50.   50.   50.   50.   50.   50.   50.   50.   50.   50.   50.]
  [  60.   60.   60.   60.   60.   60.   60.   60.   60.   60.   60.]
  [  70.   70.   70.   70.   70.   70.   70.   70.   70.   70.   70.]
  [  80.   80.   80.   80.   80.   80.   80.   80.   80.   80.   80.]
  [  90.   90.   90.   90.   90.   90.   90.   90.   90.   90.   90.]
  [ 100.  100.  100.  100.  100.  100.  100.  100.  100.  100.  100.]]
```

It updates the first dimension, this is the output for 34th index:

```
>>> print x[34,:,:,0,0]
 [[   0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.]
  [  10.   10.   10.   10.   10.   10.   10.   10.   10.   10.   10.]
  [  20.   20.   20.   20.   20.   20.   20.   20.   20.   20.   20.]
  [  30.   30.   30.   30.   30.   30.   30.   30.   30.   30.   30.]
  [  40.   40.   40.   40.   40.   40.   40.   40.   40.   40.   40.]
  [  50.   50.   50.   50.   50.   50.   50.   50.   50.   50.   50.]
  [  60.   60.   60.   60.   60.   60.   60.   60.   60.   60.   60.]
  [  70.   70.   70.   70.   70.   70.   70.   70.   70.   70.   70.]
  [  80.   80.   80.   80.   80.   80.   80.   80.   80.   80.   80.]
  [  90.   90.   90.   90.   90.   90.   90.   90.   90.   90.   90.]
  [ 100.  100.  100.  100.  100.  100.  100.  100.  100.  100.  100.]]
```

Comment: Sorry for my confusing wording. I actually want the output to look like the transpose of this (don't want the actual transpose)

Comment: ok, take a look now, you only need to reassign `x[0,:,:,0,0].T` to `x[0,:,:,0,0]`

Comment: My point is I want x[1,:,:,0,0] , x[2,:,:,0,0],  x[3,:,:,0,0] .....x[95,:,:,0,0]  to look like this too. so Im looking for something in the way I initially write to x

Comment: You don't mention that on your question, you didn't say anything about all dimension but only the first one. In any case, I have updated the answer so now all x[i,:,:,0,0] dimensions are updated

Answer (score 0):

The problem is simple: you're using a row vector for `y` instead of a column vector, so it's filling by row instead of by column.

More technically, you've got an array of shape `(11,)`, instead of an array of `(11, 1)`, so it broadcasts to `(1, 11)` when filling a 2D array.

Compare:

```
>>> x = np.zeros((96,11,11,2,10),dtype=np.float64)
>>> y = np.array([[0],[10],[20],[30],[40],[50],[60],[70],[80],[90],[100]],dtype=np.float64)
>>> x[:,:,:,0,0]=y
>>> print x[0,:,:,0,0]
[[   0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.]
 [  10.   10.   10.   10.   10.   10.   10.   10.   10.   10.   10.]
 [  20.   20.   20.   20.   20.   20.   20.   20.   20.   20.   20.]
 [  30.   30.   30.   30.   30.   30.   30.   30.   30.   30.   30.]
 [  40.   40.   40.   40.   40.   40.   40.   40.   40.   40.   40.]
 [  50.   50.   50.   50.   50.   50.   50.   50.   50.   50.   50.]
 [  60.   60.   60.   60.   60.   60.   60.   60.   60.   60.   60.]
 [  70.   70.   70.   70.   70.   70.   70.   70.   70.   70.   70.]
 [  80.   80.   80.   80.   80.   80.   80.   80.   80.   80.   80.]
 [  90.   90.   90.   90.   90.   90.   90.   90.   90.   90.   90.]
 [ 100.  100.  100.  100.  100.  100.  100.  100.  100.  100.  100.]]
```

Of course in your real code, `y` probably isn't a literal, but a result of some earlier computation. (And even if it *is* a literal, you don't want to type all those extra brackets.) So, assume `y` is inherently a row vector, as we have to deal with it.

So, just reshape it on the fly:

```
>>> x = np.zeros((96,11,11,2,10),dtype=np.float64)
>>> y = np.array([0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100],dtype=np.float64)
>>> x[:,:,:,0,0] = y.reshape((11, 1))
```

Same result.