# assigning to multi-dimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

i have a 3d array of zeros and i want to fill it with a 1d array:

```
In [136]: C = np.zeros((3,5,6),dtype=int)

In [137]: C
Out[137]: 
array([[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]])

In [138]: s
Out[138]: array([10, 20, 30, 40, 50])
```

I want to achieve this:   (without using a loop)

```
array([[[10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10],
        [20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20],
        [30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30],
        [40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40],
        [50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50]],

       [[10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10],
        [20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20],
        [30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30],
        [40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40],
        [50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50]],

       [[10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10],
        [20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20],
        [30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30],
        [40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40],
        [50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50]]])
```

by assigning s to each column of each ith element.

note I can easily get something similar:

```
array([[[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60],
        [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60],
        [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60],
        [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60],
        [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]],

       [[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60],
        [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60],
        [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60],
        [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60],
        [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]],

       [[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60],
        [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60],
        [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60],
        [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60],
        [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]]])
```

By :

```
 C[:,:,:] = s
```

But can't see how to assign s to j for all i and k in [i,j,k]

it seems numpy prioritises the last colon C[:,:,:]. is there a nice way around this?

Comment: Actually I think you should use the @atomh33ls solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tmp = C.swapaxes(1, 2)
tmp[:] = s
C = tmp.swapaxes(1, 2)
```

Answer (score 5):

You could reshape `s` from (5,) to (5,1):

```
>>> C[:] = s.reshape(5,1)
>>> C
array([[[10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10],
        [20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20],
        [30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30],
        [40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40],
        [50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50]],

       [[10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10],
        [20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20],
        [30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30],
        [40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40],
        [50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50]],

       [[10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10],
        [20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20],
        [30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30],
        [40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40],
        [50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50]]])
```

Comment: You can do the reshape more compactly as `C[:] = s[:, np.newaxis]`.